# Run tasks one by one with checks inside them

Tags: c#, task

So I have multiple different tasks which I want to run after the previous one finished.
I can do this to run them, but I need to check if the entities exist and they are alive.

```
var t1 = await spawnEntities();
if (!t1) goto cancel;

var t2 = await goToLocation();

if (!t2) goto cancel;
var t3 = await goToPed();

if (!t3) goto cancel;
await goToBase();

cancel:
   removeEntities();
```

Here is a shortened example about one of the tasks:

```
private async Task<bool> goToLocation()
{
    if (!runCheck()) return false;
    Vector3 targetLocation = Game.PlayerPed.Position;
    officer1.Task.DriveTo(targetLocation);

    if (!runCheck()) return false;
    while (!policeCar.IsInRangeOf(targetLocation, 50.0f) || !runCheck()) await Delay(500);
    if (!runCheck()) return false;
        
    return true;
}
```

The `runCheck` method checks if the entities exist and they are alive and returns a boolean. The problem is that it's a "bit" messy and I have longer more complex tasks as well and I have to check for them, otherwise if a player kills a ped it could hang up the script and throw errors.
If any of the returned bools are false it should go to the `removeEntities` which will remove those entities that exist.

What would be a better solution for this?

Comment: Are you trying to get rid of the `if (!runCheck()) return false;` statements?  They're tricky because they cause the current function to return - you can't really encapsulate that behavior

Comment: Yes, that's my main problem... I thought there is some magic way for it

Comment: Is `runCheck()` expensive?  If not, you could `if (runCheck()) { Vector3 targetLocation = Game.PlayerPed.Position;  officer1.Task.DriveTo(targetLocation); }` and so on.  The last one can be reduced to `return runCheck();`

Comment: No, it runs only null checks. Will give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rely on the short-circuiting behavior of `||`:

```
if (!await spawnEntities() 
  ||!await goToLocation()
  ||!await goToPed()
  ||!await goToBase()) {
    removeEntities();
}
```

It's certainly easier to read.

For the `runChecks()` issue, you could do something like:

```
bool allChecksAreGood;
Vector3 targetLocation;

//you will get a warning on the next line the "=" is intentional
if (allChecksAreGood = runCheck()) {
    targetLocation = Game.PlayerPed.Position;
    officer1.Task.DriveTo(targetLocation);
}

if (allChecksAreGood && (allChecksAreGood = runCheck()){
    while (!policeCar.IsInRangeOf(targetLocation, 50.0f) || !runCheck()) {
        await Delay(500);
    }
}

return allChecksAreGood && runCheck();
```

NOTE that I changed your logic somewhat, I assumed that if `goToBase()` failed, you probably wanted to `removeEntities()`.  If not, it's easy to fix.

Comment: Ah, this would be good! Yeah, I want the `removeEntities` to run anyway in the end.

Comment: *much* better than using `goto`, especially inside of an `async` method

Comment: Well, this is clearer for sure, but what about the `if (!runCheck()) return false;` inside the methods? Are there any ways to run it constantly and return false inside the method?